# What type of console println do competitive programmers use in Java?

Tags: java, performance

Which is the fastest way to write to `System.out`?
I know 3 ways so far:
1. the classic one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    System.out.println( i );
}
```

2. Using `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    sb.append(i).append("\n");
}
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

3. Wrapping `System.out` in a Buffer like:

```
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    out.write((i + "\n").getBytes());
}
out.flush();
```

Is there any method that is more efficient than all of these?

Comment: Competitive java programming is rarely about who can print hundreds of thousands of lines to the console the fastest.